# Selecting username and email from database if already there using php prepared statement

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I'm creating a registration form.. in which I want to check if any username and email id is present in the database, then I want to display a message that email or username is already registered using php prepared statement, I'm not able to do this.
Please look at my code. Where I'm wrong?

```
<?php  
include 'config.php';

$name=check_input($_POST['name']);
$username=check_input($_POST['username']);
$email=check_input($_POST['email']);
$phone=check_input($_POST['phone']);
$pass=check_input($_POST['pass']);
$cpass=check_input($_POST['cpass']);
$pass=md5($pass);
$cpass=md5($cpass);
$created=date('Y-m-d');

$name=$conn->real_escape_string($name);
$username=$conn->real_escape_string($username);
$email=$conn->real_escape_string($email);
$phone=$conn->real_escape_string($phone);
$pass=$conn->real_escape_string($pass);

if($pass==$cpass){

    $sql=$conn->prepare("SELECT username,email FROM users WHERE username=? OR email=?");
    $sql->bind_param("ss",$username,$email);
$sql->execute();
$sql->store_result();
if($row=$sql->num_rows==1){
    if($username==$row['username']){
    echo "Username not available try different!";
    }
    if($email==$row['email']){
        echo "Email already exists!";
    }
}
else{
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO users (name, username, email, phone, pass, created) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
        $stmt->bind_param("sssiss", $name,$username,$email,$phone,$pass,$created);
        if($stmt->execute()){
            echo"Registered Successfully. Login Now!";
        }
        else{
            echo "Something went wrong!";
        }
}
}
else{
    echo "Password didn't matched!";
}
function check_input($data){
    $data=trim($data);
    $data=stripslashes($data);
    $data=htmlspecialchars($data);
    return $data;
}
?>
```

Comment: Have you tried any basic debugging such as echoing the raw `$_POST` data?

Comment: "But I'm not able to do this", can you elaborate on that? What is the exact problem? What are the error messages? What is happening and what is not happening?

Comment: Don't use real_escape_string(), you don't need it for prepared statements. Actually, it would change the values in an unwanted way.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the suggestion guys! But I've fixed this issue myself. Here is the updated codes.

```
<?php  
include 'config.php';

$name=check_input($_POST['name']);
$username=check_input($_POST['username']);
$email=check_input($_POST['email']);
$phone=check_input($_POST['phone']);
$pass=check_input($_POST['pass']);
$cpass=check_input($_POST['cpass']);
$pass=md5($pass);
$cpass=md5($cpass);
$created=date('Y-m-d');

if($pass==$cpass){

    $sql=$conn->prepare("SELECT username,email FROM users WHERE username=? OR email=?");
    $sql->bind_param("ss",$username,$email);
    $sql->execute();
    $result=$sql->get_result();
    $row=$result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    if($row['username']==$username){
     echo "Username not available try different!";
    }
    elseif($row['email']==$email){
     echo "Email already registered try different!";
    }
   else{
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO users (name, username, email, phone, pass, created) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
        $stmt->bind_param("sssiss", $name,$username,$email,$phone,$pass,$created);
        if($stmt->execute()){
            echo"Registered Successfully. Login Now!";
        }
        else{
            echo "Something went wrong!";
        }
    }
}
else{
    echo "Password didn't matched!";
}
function check_input($data){
    $data=trim($data);
    $data=stripslashes($data);
    $data=htmlspecialchars($data);
    return $data;
}
```

?>